# Photos taken from Android Application are unable to load on Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Tags: android, django, linux, image-processing, ubuntu-16.04

I have an android application that allows the user to take a picture from the gallery or from the camera. I also have a server that allows the user to upload the image and share it with other users.

The android application works without the use of internet, so in order to share, the user who took the picture uploads it to the server. The server is running on a Django web framework, so it stores the image in a media folder. When another user syncs to the server, the image is then downloaded to that device.

The problem is that the image is unable to display. The file is there on the Linux machine, but when you try to open it, it gives and error: "Could not load image 'XX.jpg' Failed to open input stream for file.

I have tested this on an older android device and the linux machine is able to open the images, but on this newer device, the images are unable to open.

I am not sure what the problem could be.
This is how I am handling saving the image:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap image = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (image != null) {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File directory = new File(root + "/instrumentImages");
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }
            String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/instrumentImages", fileName);
            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.close();

                //Check to see if there was a previous image. If so, delete it.
                if (details.getImage() != null) {
                    if (!details.getImage().equals("")) {
                        File oldFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/instrumentImages", details.getImage());
                        oldFile.delete();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(requestCode == 0) { //If the user takes a picture with the camera. A picture is saved to the gallery, so we must delete it.
                if(data.getData()!= null) {
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(data.getData(), null, null);
                }
            }
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(destination).into(instrumentImage);
            instrumentImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            helper = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity());
            database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            helper.setInstrumentImage(database, details.getPk(), fileName);
            helper.close();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the image is being posted through retrofit:

```
private void postPhoto(String sessionId, final int pk, final String photoName){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(root + "/instrumentImages/" + photoName);
    RequestBody requestFile =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = client.uploadPhoto(sessionId, body, String.valueOf(pk));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("ActionSync", "The response from post image: " + response.toString());
            helper.updateInstrumentEditedStatus(database, pk);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("ActionSync", "No response from uploadImage");
            activity.CancelSyncTask("Failed to upload image.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's the code to save the image locally on the android device, but you're saying the image downloaded from the server is the problem. So shouldn't we look at how you upload the image and save it on the server? Also, have you tried opening the link to image (saved on your server) in a normal browser?

Comment: Yes, I have tried opening the link in a normal browser and it shows a blank box. I believe that it is going to be an android problem because I am able to use a different device and it works for that one.

Comment: Maybe on your Django app, try using PIL library to change the image to jpeg (again), see if you can figure out if it's an encoding issue. If the uploaded image is problematic, PIL might give you a meaningful error. If not, it might convert it into a format that everyone can read. You could even first try from the command-line, in a python shell, downloading the file first to your local machine.

Comment: I am already using the Pillow library :'(

Comment: and it's not throwing any errors? can you see the size of the file, its resolution? Just download it locally and open it with PIL, try a few functions on it. There must be a reason it doesn't render. Maybe opacity is 0. Or it's empty, or resolution is tiny...

Comment: It is saying "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image" I don't know why it wouldn't be an image or corrupted because it was compressed and saved as a jpg

Comment: ok, then the issue is definitely with your android code and not with your file handler on django side. sorry can't help further from here, we need an android expert now :-) Is it possible newer Android versions use a different file format, e.g. HEIC?